# How to store data for each account in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Now I have developed an app in **Flutter**  and also added **firebase_auth** now what I want is that each user when is logged in could set a value to a variable, let's say variable your **Phone Number** which every user has to set once they log in not I want to ask if the user logs in another device how am I gonna make sure the variable **Phone Number** is same as he set in the other device.

I know that I could store that data locally using **SQL** or **sharedpreferences** but in firebase how should I do?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-authentication%5D+store+additional+data+for+user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical approach is to create a `Users` collection. Every user that signs up will have a dedicated document (in the `Users` collection) for you to store other data related to that user; you can use the UID provided by `firebase_auth` for the `documentID` to make it easier to reference.

Comment: using realtime database?

Comment: Either Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore can be used for this.